# Best way to test if all elements of an array/list satisfy a condition

Tags: for-loop, optimization

I would like to test if all elements in an array (or list) satisfy a condition. But I would like to do it in the cleanest and most optimized way I can.

I used to do something like this (exemple in c++) :

```
vector<unsigned> vct; // put anything in it
bool verified = true;

for (unsigned elmt: vct) {
    if (!mycondition) {
        verified = false;
        break;
    }
} // then use verified to check if condition is satisfied for each element
```

But then someone told me that you usally want to initialize `verified` to `false` and then turn it to `true`. This made me do :

```
vector<unsigned> vct; // put anything in it
bool verified = false;
unsigned count = 0;

for (unsigned elmt: vct) {
    if (mycondition) {
        ++count;
    }
}

if(count == vct.size())
    verified = true; // then use verified to check if condition is satisfied for each element
```

But this solution does not seem optimized at all because we use a counter and we have to loop through all the elements while the first solution stopped as soon as it finds a "bad" element.

So here is my question.
What is the cleaner and most optimized way to test if all elements in array satisfy a condition ?

Comment: if you need to know how many elements failed condition - 2nd, if not - first

Comment: first way. you also need to consider if an empty list should be considered "verified".

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But is there any way to "mix" both solutions ? I figured out that nothing stops me from using `break` in the second solution so we don't have to iterate over every elements. But there's still the counter...